# Prevent html loading before data loading in knockout mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

**HTML:**

```
<div id="knockoutBinding">
    <div class="toolbar" data-bind="template: 'user-portfolio-entry' "></div>
</div>

<script id="user-portfolio-entry" type="text/html">
<!-- ko if: vm.currentPortfolioEntry().hasOwnProperty('Step') -->
//other stuff
<!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var UserPortfolioViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.currentPortfolioEntry = ko.observable(null);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: getPortfolioEntryUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(data1),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                self.currentPortfolioEntry(ko.mapping.fromJS(response));
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
}
var vm;
    $(function () {
         vm = new UserPortfolioViewModel();
         ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#knockoutBinding")[0]);
    });
```

I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "template: function
>   (){return 'user-portfolio-entry' }" Message: Unable to process binding
>   "if: function (){return
>   vm.currentPortfolioEntry().hasOwnProperty('Step') }" Message: Cannot
>   read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null

and when the line in ajax success is executed `self.currentPortfolioEntry(ko.mapping.fromJS(response));` then I can see the value of `vm.currentPortfolioEntry().hasOwnProperty('Step')` in console but at that time html had finished loading and I can't get data in html.

How to load the html after the success of ajax, so that properties can be mapped. Or any other way to tackle this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor your `if` to test if the variable exits like following :

```
<!-- ko if:  vm.currentPortfolioEntry() && vm.currentPortfolioEntry().hasOwnProperty('Step') -->
```

Comment: ok, it will say the variable exist but don't have the property `step` and the data inside this html will not be loaded but actually the data should be loaded because it will come from ajax call.

Comment: @IrfanYusanif I'm not sure I understand. Before your ajax call, `currentPortfolioEntry` will be null, therefore `if` content won't be added to DOM. After that call, if `currentPortfolioEntry` contains `Step` then if content will be shown. What do you want more ?